# How to schedule my crawler function in django periodically using celery?

Tags: django, web-scraping, django-views, celery

Here I have a view `CrawlerHomeView` which is used to create the task object from a form now I want to schedule this task periodically with celery.

I want to schedule this `CrawlerHomeView` process with the  task object search_frequency and by checking some task object fields.

Task Model

```
class Task(models.Model):
    INITIAL = 0
    STARTED = 1
    COMPLETED = 2

    task_status = (
        (INITIAL, 'running'),
        (STARTED, 'running'),
        (COMPLETED, 'completed'),
        (ERROR, 'error')
    )

    FREQUENCY = (
        ('1', '1 hrs'),
        ('2', '2 hrs'),
        ('6', '6 hrs'),
        ('8', '8 hrs'),
        ('10', '10 hrs'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    scraping_end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    search_frequency = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True, choices=FREQUENCY)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=task_status)
```

tasks.py

I want to run the view below posted periodically [period=(task's search_frequency time] if the task status is 0 or 1 and not crossed the task scraping end date. But I got stuck here. How can I do this?

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour="task.search_frequency"))  # how to do  with task search_frequency value
def schedule_task(pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if task.status == 0 or task.status == 1 and not datetime.date.today() > task.scraping_end_date:

        # perform the crawl function ---> def crawl() how ??

        if task.scraping_end_date == datetime.date.today():
            task.status = 2
            task.save()  # change the task status as complete.
```

views.py

I want to run this view periodically.How can I do it?

```
class CrawlerHomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = 'users:login'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # all_task = Task.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        frequency = Task()
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        targets = TargetSite.objects.all()
        keywords = Keyword.objects.all()

        form = CreateTaskForm()
        context = {
            'targets': targets,
            'keywords': keywords,
            'frequency': frequency,
            'form':form,
            'categories': categories,
        }
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form = CreateTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # try:
            unique_id = str(uuid4()) # create a unique ID. 
            obj = form.save(commit=False)

            # obj.keywords = keywords
            obj.created_by = request.user
            obj.unique_id = unique_id
            obj.status = 0
            obj.save()
            form.save_m2m()

            keywords = ''
            # for keys in ast.literal_eval(obj.keywords.all()): #keywords change to csv
            for keys in obj.keywords.all():
                if keywords:
                    keywords += ', ' + keys.title
                else:
                    keywords += keys.title
            # tasks = request.POST.get('targets')
            # targets = ['thehimalayantimes', 'kathmandupost']
            # print('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ keywords', keywords)

            task_ids = [] #one Task/Project contains one or multiple scrapy task

            settings = {
                'spider_count' : len(obj.targets.all()),
                'keywords' : keywords,
                'unique_id': unique_id, # unique ID for each record for DB
                'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
            }

            # res = ast.literal_eval(ini_list) 

            for site_url in obj.targets.all():
                domain = urlparse(site_url.address).netloc # parse the url and extract the domain
                spider_name = domain.replace('.com', '')
                task = scrapyd.schedule('default', spider_name, settings=settings, url=site_url.address, domain=domain, keywords=keywords)

            # task = scrapyd.schedule('default', spider_name , settings=settings, url=obj.targets, domain=domain, keywords=obj.keywords)
            return redirect('crawler:task-list')
            # except:
            #     return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form, 'errors':form.errors})
```

**Any Suggestions or answer is there for this problem ?**

Comment: What kind of field is Task.frequency? DurationField?

Comment: @mark show your `scheduler.models.Task` implementation

Comment: @ncopiy updated in the qiestion

Comment: @Ben updated in the question

Answer (score 9):

After fighting Celery for 5 years in a 15k tasks/second setup I highly recommend you to switch to [Dramatiq,](https://dramatiq.io/) which has a sane, reliable, performant code base that isn't split across multiple convoluted packages and works perfectly in two of my newer projects so far.

From the [author's motivation](https://dramatiq.io/motivation.html#compared-to)

> I’ve used Celery professionally for years and my growing frustration with it is one of the reasons why I developed dramatiq. Here are some of the main differences between Dramatiq, Celery and RQ:

There's also a a Django helper package: https://github.com/Bogdanp/django_dramatiq

Granted, you won't have a builtin celerybeat, but a cron calling python tasks is more robust anyway, we lost a good amount of data because celerybeat decided to stall regularly :)

---

There are two projects that aim to add periodic task creation: https://gitlab.com/bersace/periodiq and https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

I haven't used those packages yet, what you could try with periodiq is selecting your database entries, loop through those and define a periodic-task for each (but this requires regular restarts of the periodiq worker to pick up changes):

```py
# tasks.py
from dramatiq import get_broker
from periodiq import PeriodiqMiddleware, cron

broker = get_broker()
broker.add_middleware(PeriodiqMiddleware(skip_delay=30))


for obj in Task.objects.all():
   @dramatiq.actor(periodic=cron(obj.frequency))
   def hourly(obj=obj):
       # import logic based on obj.name
       # Do something each hour…
```

Comment: Seems easier but I have to use the time duration from the database tables can i schedule the task like this way in dramatiq.

Comment: @mark: updated with example code, it's just an idea how this might work with your db based schedules :)

Comment: here in periodiq `@dramatiq.actor(periodic=cron('0 * * * *))`. what should be the value of ** ?secs/minutes/hours/? what is the format ? can you tell since I didn't find it in the docs.

Comment: @user12428848 see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron for cron-syntax. `0 * * * *` basically says "run this cron every full hour on the minute 0" (01:00 am, 02:00 am, 03:00 am, ...).

Comment: thanks. But when I run on the terminal with command `periodiq -v app` ii throws this error 
`[2020-07-20 22:01:07,160] [PID 2188] [MainThread] [periodiq] [CRITICAL] Unsupported system: alarm syscall is not available.
`

Comment: does periodiq run on windows OS too ? Since I am using windows and it throws this error when I run the command `alarm syscall is not available.`

Comment: @user12428848 nope, cron is a unix-concept - if you aren't developing windows-software and aren't required to host on a windows server (which no sane person should do, anyway, as it is a security nightmare - even Microsoft hosts most of their infrastructure on Linux) you should switch to a developer-centric operating system, preferably a well maintained Linux distribution (for a beginner, I would recommend Ubuntu as a debian-based system) :)

Comment: I run the command `periodiq -v tasks` .but it throws this error.`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'`.

Answer (score 3):

For the error,

```
Exception Type: EncodeError
Exception Value:    
Object of type timedelta is not JSON serializable
```

Instead of defining following variable in django settings,

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {

    'task-first': {
    'task': 'scheduler.tasks.create_task',
    'schedule': timedelta(minutes=1)
   },
```

can you try following in your celery file:

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'task-first': {
        'task': 'scheduler.tasks.create_task',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1')
    }
}
```

this works for me given, celery server is up and running.

Apart from this why are you redirecting to `'list_tasks'` after each task, what does it exactly do? Also, you have called the celery task from the view `add_task_celery.delay(name,date,freq)`, is it just another way to add task apart from periodic task defined using celery-beat?

**Edit 1:**

My structure looks like as follow:

settings.py

```
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
```

celery.py

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'task1': {
        'task': '<app_name>.tasks.random_task',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=0)
    },
}
```

Here you should note that I have a file named tasks in my app folder and there I have written a shared task as follow:

```
@shared_task
def random_task(total):
    ...
```

Also, apart from this you should start both celery beat as well as a celery worker process as follow:

```
celery -A <project_name>.celery worker -l error
celery -A <project_name>.celery beat -l error --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

You can any scheduler you want, on production I use `DatabaseScheduler`. For testing you can try with following command:

```
celery -A <project_name> beat -l info -S django
```

You should run all these commands from the project folder of the Django project

Comment: thanks for the answer. This is my very first time with celery so this happened and I also think this is not the proper way to call the task.Can you help me to instruct how can i schedule task here.What will be the step by step process. I want to create Task object every 1 minute in the database and want to show the result after 1 minute in list_tasks page

Comment: Updated my answer for step by step process

Comment: i've edited my question can you please look through this ?

Comment: You have completely changed the question. Why don't you make a function with it taking all the parameters you want to take and call that function from both views and task. Also, rather than calling view from task, you should call that function from celery task and provide all the necessary parameter. Basically, rather than writing all of your code in view you should write a reusable function that you should call both from celery and views.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is with 2nd and 3rd parameter in the task definition, which is `freq` and `date`. Although from the error, you posted, `Object of type timedelta is not JSON serializable`, it looks like it's talking about `freq` field which is of type DurationField that returns timedelta object.

Ideally, both fields must be serialized before passing to the task.
one simple way would be -

1) You can explicitly serialize these fields and pass to the task and in the task again convert it to datetime / timedelta object.

alternatively, you can dump whole data dict if there are too many items.

`add_task_celery.delay(json.dumps(form.cleaned_data))`,

and then in the task do -> `json.loads(...)`

2) Another thing you can try is to pass the serializer in the parameters explicitly.(using `apply_async` instead of `delay`)

`add_task_celery.apply_async((name, date, freq), serializer='json')`

3) You can also set value, if you haven't already, for setting `CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'` (default value is `'pickle'`).

Comment: add_task_celery() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serializer' while using 2nd approach

Comment: `add_task_celery() argument after ** must be a mapping, not datetime.date` after using apply_async

Comment: I have a form to create the task object So i fill up the form with correct inputs(which works before using celery) and then after submit I throws this error.Celery version is 4+

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215280/discussion-between-mark-and-gaurav-jain).

Comment: He's already serializing with json, otherwise he wouldn't have a json serializer error. The problem is that you can't easily register another serializer at runtime, but have to do it with Kombu at setup time. The [DjangoJSONEncoder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder) would already solve the issue as it supports serializing temporals.